# Testing Unity build on remote?

Tags: unity-game-engine

my question probably doesn't belong here because it's not really code-related, but I've no idea where to ask this kind of stuff :/

I'm currently working on a an indie game, will probably leave my job to invest 100% of my time doing so (I know it's probably dumb but w/e).

I've already started, and have a prototype that I update daily. Even if I only target PC .exe build for the final product, I'm currently building to WebGL and hosting on heroku to show the progression and get feedback from friends, as they only have to click and the link to get the project starting.
Problem is : a lot of functionnality are not supported on WebGL, and as the project will grow it will only be worse.

What I'm looking for is a solution, maybe a VM, to put my .exe build on, and give remote access to my friends so they can try out the game without having to download everything at every update.

Is there some existing tools that could do that (something like Shadow maybe ?), or is there a possibility to update only the files that were updated when I build a new version of the game ? (Because everything is bundled when you build, so everything changes and I can't update per-file).

Sorry again to ask that here, but I'd really like some help on that !

Thanks a lot

Comment: having a patch system in place is a common problem, Im sure theres info out there on making a patching system

Answer (score 0):

If you will use some remote access solution then you will get a lot of troubles with slow internet connection and bad latency, especially if you are making an action game.
Maybe, it will be easier to continue support WebGL. You can upgrade your project to WebGL 2.0 if you have not already done it. WebGL 2.0 is not as limited as 1.0.

Comment: 1. As I said, it is only for super early showcase / getting feedback from friends.
2. I don't plan to suppoirt WebGL, it's way to limited and won't handle a "big" game

Comment: Then it must be a patch system, not an remote access solution. You can't put your unfinished game on some game streaming service. And game streaming is the only playable and reliable solution for remote access.